# Is the path correct?

Tags: code-golf, string

## Is the path correct ?

Given a string, your program must determine whether or not Alice can reach Bob, following the signs on the map. You must return a truthy or falsy value.

The input string will contain the following characters :

- (space) and `\n`. Only used for padding.
- `>`, `<`, `^`, `v`, are the "signs". They show the direction.
- `&`. Ignore next char, whatever it is (including spaces **and `Bob`**)
- `A` and `B` respectively Alice and Bob.

The map is a torus. If Alice reaches the end of a row, then she is teleported back to the beginning of that row. Same applies for columns.

### Examples

Given those examples as input, your program must return a truthy value (each input is separated with a `-` line):

```
A>B
-----------------
<BA
-----------------
A       B
-----------------
BA
-----------------
Av  >B
 >  ^
-----------------
Av
 B
-----------------
A>v
  >B
-----------------
A>v>   v>B
 v< > &<^
 > ^
-----------------
A>v>   v
 v< >B&<
 > ^
-----------------
A&<B
-----------------
A&B<
-----------------
<A       &B
```

For the following, your program must output a falsy value or nothing :

```
AvB
-----------------
A&B
-----------------
A><B
-----------------
A>v
 ^<B
```

### Path viewer

You can have a visual representation of the input [here](https://correctpath.firebaseapp.com/). Thanks to arnemart for [this](https://github.com/arnemart/befungius).

### Some rules

- The input may be padded with spaces to form a rectangle
- Initially, Alice goes straight forward (from above, she goes to the right)
- Your program ***should*** handle infinite loop cases (see Hint)
- `A` is not always the first character, as you may have seen, however, you may write a program that handles only input with `A` being the first char, but 20 bytes will be added to your score.
- A map (the input) is considered invalid in case there are other characters than those specified above. Your program won't have to handle them.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Hint

Your program will most likely be a loop, unless you find a more mathematical solution to this challenge. To handle infinite path, I recommend using a finite loop (e.g `for`) instead of a potentially infinite one (e.g `while`).

Therefore, the maximum iteration of the loop I can think of (I did not do any maths, any correction is welcome) is `(length of input)*4`

Comment: Closely related -- http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57952/42963

Comment: Can the input be padded with spaces so that it forms a rectangle and each line is the same length?

Comment: @user81655 Yes it can

Comment: If only there was a way to replace a few chars then exec in ><>...

Comment: @mbomb007  Sorry :D

Comment: [Also related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65546/8478)

Comment: Alice is a male? o_O

Comment: Can I take the input as a string array passed to the main method of a Java program?

Comment: @AlexL. Yes you can. I think someone corrected the `he`. But orignially, Alice was in fact John (which I replaced to match `A` and `B`, and also because [Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) are well known)

Comment: @FliiFe Okay. Thanks. `B` will always be present, right?

Comment: @AlexL. Yes. You basically don't have do handle any unexpected input.

Comment: @AlexL. She **was** a male. I turn**ed** her to a female on my **last** edit. Just didn't press [s] well, I think.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 250 bytes

```
#define h x=(j+x-1+d%3)%j,i=(j+i+(d=='v')-(d==94))%j
char a[999],b[999];x,i,d=2,k,f;main(j){for(;gets(a+j*i);)j=strlen(a+j*i++);for(x=strchr(a,65)-a,i=x/j,x=x%j;!k*d;h)k|=b[f=j*i+x]&1<<d%5,b[f]|=1<<d%5,(f=a[f])&16?d=f:f&4?h:f&2?d=0:0;putchar(48+!k);}
```

This also requires that the input is padded with spaces.

Ungolfed:

```
#define h x=(j+x-1+d%3)%j,i=(j+i+(d=='v')-(d==94))%j 
char a[999],b[999];x,i,d=2,k,f;
main(j){
 for(;gets(a+j*i);)j=strlen(a+j*i++); //read lines and determine line length
 for(x=strchr(a,65)-a,i=x/j,x=x%j;    //the current position is 'A'
 !k*d; //as long as we have not arrived at 'B' 
       //and not travelled through the same cell and in the same direction twice
 h)    //advance one in the current direction
   k|=b[f=j*i+x]&1<<d%5,b[f]|=1<<d%5,  //if we have already travelled  
                                       //through this cell in this direction
   (f=a[f])&16?d=f //change direction if this cell is one of <>^v
   :f&4?h          //if this cell is '&', advance one in the current direction
   :f&2?d=0:0;     //if we have reached 'B'
 putchar(48+!k);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 176 bytes

```js
m=>[...m,q=~m.length,l=~m.search`
`||q,a=m.search`A`,p=d=r=1].map(_=>(a+=d,a-=d*((a-l+1)%l?m[a]?0:q/l:~l),c=m[a],p=="&"?0:d={">":1,"<":-1,"^":l,v:-l}[c=="B"?r=0:c]||d,p=c))&&!r
```

### Explanation

Requires the input to be space-padded to form a rectangle (I hope this is OK).

```js
var solution =

m=>[
    ...m,                           // iterate m.length times
    q=~m.length,                    // q = total length of m
    l=~m.search`\n`||q,             // l = line length
    a=m.search`A`,                  // a = index of Alice
    p=                              // p = previous character
    d=                              // d = direction offset
    r=1                             // r = result
  ].map(_=>(                        // loop
    a+=d,                           // move Alice
    a-=d*((a-l+1)%l?m[a]?0:q/l:~l), // wrap
    c=m[a],
    p=="&"?0:                       // do nothing after &
    d={">":1,"<":-1,"^":l,v:-l}     // set the new direction
      [c=="B"?r=0:c]                // if on Bob, r = 0
    ||d,
    p=c
  ))&&!r                            // return result

var testCasesTrue =
`A>B
-----------------
<BA
-----------------
A       B
-----------------
BA
-----------------
Av  >B
 >  ^ 
-----------------
Av
 B
-----------------
A>v 
  >B
-----------------
A>v>   v>B
 v< > &<^ 
 > ^      
-----------------
A>v>   v
 v< >B&<
 > ^    
-----------------
A&<B
-----------------
A&B<
-----------------
<A       &B`
.split("\n-----------------\n");

var testCasesFalse =
`AvB
-----------------
A&B
-----------------
A><B
-----------------
A>v 
 ^<B`
.split("\n-----------------\n");

var test = (cases, expected) => cases.map((t,i)=>++i+": "+(solution(t)==expected?"Pass":"Fail")).join`\n`;
document.write(`<pre>${test(testCasesTrue,true)}\n\n${test(testCasesFalse,false)}</pre>`);
```

Comment: Congratulations !